# Pipeline build with a Docker agent, then Jenkins itself

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set up a Jenkinsfile that first uses a build tool in a Docker image which should leave a jar file in the workspace, then outside of that Docker image uses Jenkins Docker plugin to build a Docker image around that jar file and publish to my local Docker repo.  My pipeline is as follows:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'myrepo:5500/openjdk11_ant_buildenv'
        }

      }
      steps {
        sh 'ant'
      }
    }

    stage('Containerize') {
      agent any
      steps {
        script {
           withDockerRegistry([url: 'http://myrepo:5500']){
              def image = docker.build("myrepo:5500/myimagename", "--pull .");
              image.push()
           }
        }
    }
  }
}
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the second stage doesn't appear to have the same workspace as the first stage so that jar file isn't there.

How do I pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could try:

[stash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) and [unstash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#unstash-restore-files-previously-stashed) your jar file between stages if the jar is quite small

use a [multistage docker build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) so run the ant step in stage one then copy the jar file from stage 1 to stage 2 and do what you're doing in stage 2 to build the image. This is nice because you're not then reliant on your ci tool - nice as Jenkins is it is still painful to iterate it when you're developing it

Answer (score 0):

The secret seems to be adding reuseNode true to the docker agent.  This prevents it from creating a new workspace for that stage so the built artifact stays where needed for the Containerize stage.

'''
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
stage('build') {
agent { docker {
image 'myrepo:5500/openjdk11_ant_buildenv'
reuseNode true
}
}
steps {
sh 'ant'
}
}
stage('Containerize') {
steps {
script {
withDockerRegistry([url: 'http://myrepo:5500']){
def image = docker.build("myrepo:5500/myimagename", "--pull .");
image.push()
}
}
}
}
}
}
'''